# Arranging objects by mass

Tags: experimental-physics, mathematical-physics, computational-physics, applied-physics, laws-of-physics

I have n objects with different  masses . 
Say mass of n1=m1, n2=m2 .... so on.
I want to use concept of centrality in physics to arrange these objects in a field (computer simulation ) . Where object with biggest mass occupy the center and above it all the other objects .

Is it correct to define the centrality as the mass here? 
I need some ideas or reading resources to do so. 
Thank you in advance for your precious help.

Comment: What is the force field? gravity?

Comment: Force field . Like attraction and repulsion .

Comment: @patta you can say gravity field, yes.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me (hopefully), but I can't get what concept of centrality is. Could you give more explanations?

Comment: @Helen hi, By centrality I mean the object with the highest mass should be in the center of the field the others also should arrange themselves according to their mass . Form example if the m1 is the object with highest mass, m2 is the object with second highest mass, then m1 is first to locate itself in the field and m2 above it . Now if m3 mass is bigger than m1 , then m3 should repulse m1 and take its position, so that always the first , say level , or shell , or center is occupied by the object with highest mass .

Comment: But what physics process does this correspond to?

Comment: @Helen that is what I am looking for, if there is a physics law helps to do such .

Comment: Maybe electrons in an atom can be an example. The lower electrons (in the centre) have more binding energy (your mass) ?  For gravity, may be different, in the solar system we have Jupiter that is big but not near the sun

Comment: Thanks!  Another example - but with different "distance": the atomic nuclei; there is the "mass formula" that tells the weight of nuclei; Iron is the lightest (per nucleon) and is central, in the sense that all other atoms and isotopes tend to decay to Iron. The field can be  nuclear stability

Comment: @patta can you suggest some searching keywords for this last idea so that Incan read more about it  ? Thank you.

Comment: You may look at "decay chain" in nuclear physics, that is a nice discrete network  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_chain  , it is for heavy nuclei; Iron/nickel centrality is in Stellar Nucleosythesis  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_nucleosynthesis

Comment: The same game is done with excited electron orbital around an atom (central: ground state)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excited_state